# Disk utilization on mdadm raid 5 is 100% even though none of the member disks is at 100%

Tags: hard-disk, performance, raid, btrfs, mdadm

I am currently confused about the disk utilisation of one of my machines.

The setup:

I have a machine containing 4 2TB HDDs.
For those HDDs I used mdadm to configure a RAID 5 (called md2)
On MD2, I am using a luks-volume containing a btrfs filesystem.

Besides other use cases, I also have samba installed and use it to share files and create a TimeMachine Backup.

When copying over large files, I am able to use the complete 1G connection of the machine to read and write files. So regarding this, I am happy with the speed I get.

When it comes to timemachine backups (I assume, this causes non-sequential reads/writes) the transfer starts to be very slow.

The machine is not swapping and the CPU utilization is fine as well.

When looking at netdata, I see that the utilization for "root-crypted" is constantly on 100% (root-crypted is the name of the mounted file system).

I would then expect at least one of the HDDs to also be utilized at 100%, but actually none of them is. (They all are between 40 and 60%)
Now I am wondering, why the raid does not utilize the disks by 100%.

I assume, that I might be able to improve the performance by maybe 20% if I would just manage to have the raid utilizing the disks by 100%.

Is my thinking here correct or am I missing / misunderstanding something here.
Sadly my knowledge about disks and filesystems is not good enough to understand this.
Would be cool, if you could give me some support here.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Isn't the encryption layer the bottleneck? Note that btrfs in my experience is slow with lots of metadata updates.

Comment: I also thought about that. but wouldn't I then experience 100% CPU load, or does the encryption-part not count into that?